# MySQL slow query joining two tables with fulltext condition on each

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I need to join two tables (1M rows and 10M rows respectively)

Each table is filtered with a fulltext match condition :

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE c.company_index
    
FROM dw.companies c INNER JOIN dw.people p 
ON c.company_index = p.company_index
    
WHERE MATCH ( c.tag ) AGAINST ( 'ecommerce' IN BOOLEAN MODE )
AND MATCH ( p.title ) AGAINST ( 'director' IN BOOLEAN MODE )
    
ORDER BY c.company_index DESC ;
```

Both tables have fulltext indexes (on "tag" and "title")

The query time is more than 1 mn with both conditions.

With only one of the two conditions, the query time is below 1 sec.

How could I optimize this query ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that FULLTEXT is very fast if it can be performed *first*, but very slow if not.  With both of the tests in the original query, one MATCH can be first, but the other cannot be.

Here's a messy idea on how to work around the problem.

```
SELECT c.company_index
    FROM ( SELECT company_index FROM companies WHERE MATCH... ) AS c
    JOIN ( SELECT company_index FROM people    WHERE MATCH... ) AS p
       ON c.company_index
        = p.company_index
    ORDER BY ...
```

What version of MySQL are you using?  Newer versions will automatically create an index on one of the 'derived' tables, thereby making the `JOIN` quite efficient.

Here's another approach:

```
SELECT c.company_index
    FROM ( SELECT company_index FROM companies WHERE MATCH... ) AS c
    WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM people WHERE MATCH...
                      AND company_index = c.company_index )
    ORDER BY ...
```

In both cases (I hope) one `SELECT` will use one FT index; the other will use the other, thereby getting the FT performance benefit.

Comment: HI ! Thanks for your suggestion. I tried both but the query is even slower, probably because it cannot user the index on company_index anymore to make the join.

Comment: What mysql version are you using?

Comment: Actually its mariadb 10.3